# How can I copy a folder structure from one server to another keeping the same owner and permissions?

Tags: filesystems

How can I copy a folder structure from one server to another keeping the same owner and file permissions?

Comment: Would you like to comment about why you down voted this question?

Comment: The question doesn't have any downvotes, so if somebody did downvote it they took it back pretty fast

Comment: I found some more answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/81789/how-to-replicate-the-directory-structure-to-a-remote-linux-server I searched for this question like crazy before posting and I now I have found it again.

Answer (score 4):

Using -a option with the rsync command you can transfer the file between server under same ownership and perm.

Synchronise between local and remote server

```
#rsync -avz /source username@192.168.200.10:/destination
```

Synchronise between local and remote over ssh.

```
%rsync -avz -e ssh username@192.168.200.10:/source /destination
```

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` with `-a` will copy ownership and permissions. It will even work over ssh.